# Is it possible to derive $B$ from $AB=C$ when $B$ is not invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be an $m\times n$ matrix, $B$ be an $n\times k$ non-invertible matrix (where $n<k$) and $C=AB$. If we have $C$ and $A$, can we derive $B$?

Comment: If A is m-by-n and the rank of A is equal to n, then A has a left inverse, which can be applied to both sides of the equation to yield B.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for a pseudo-inverse of $A$, $A^+$, since if it exists you could write:
$$C = AB \ \to \ A^+C = A^+ A B=B$$
If the rows of $A$ are independent, then the pseudo inverse is given by:
$$A^+ = A^*(A A^*)^{-1}$$ 
Where $A^*$ is the Hermitian transpose.

Comment: I think pseudo inverse is not helping here, because B is non-invertible, and the product of an invertible and a non-invertible matrices would be a non-invertible matrix. I am thinking if it is possible to get B using, e.g. elimination or something similar.

Comment: @user1468089 - the whole point here is that the pseudo inverse is non-invertible, but still helps you find $B$. Try it yourself and see.

Comment: But if A be m*n and m<n then it wont be possible to use pseudo inverse, am I right?

Comment: @user1468089 - if A has more rows then columns, then yes, you'll have a problem. As said, the condition is that the rows of A are independent,

Answer (score 2):

Let $B_1$ and $B_2$ matrices such that $C=AB_1$ and $C=AB_2$. Then
$$
A(B_1-B_2)=0.
$$

Conversely, if $X$ is any $n\times k$ matrix such that $AX=0$ and $C=AB$, then
$$
A(B+X)=AB+AX=C+0=C.
$$

You can thus recover $B$ if and only if the unique solution of $AX=0$ is the zero matrix. This is true if and only if the unique solution of $Av=0$ ($v$ an $m$-row vector) is $v=0$, which is equivalent to $A$ having a left inverse, that is
$$
m\ge n=\operatorname{rank}(A)
$$

Comment: Sorry I am a bit confused, A having a left inverse means m>n, did you mean having a right inverse (n>=m)?

Comment: @user1468089 A typo, sorry.